# On Normed Spaces Being Also Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Before asking the part that I doubt, let me give the definition of normed space in the book with which I study.

Definiton: Let $X$ be a vector space over the field $R$. Then the mapping $\rho : X \rightarrow [0,\infty ) $ with the following properties is called $\textbf{a norm} $ on $X$.
$$ 1) \rho(x) =0 \Rightarrow x=0 , \forall x \in X, $$
$$2) \rho(cx)= \lvert c \rvert \rho(x), \forall x \in X , \forall c\in R $$
$$3)\rho(x+y) \leq \rho(x) + \rho(y) , \forall x,y \in X .$$
A proposition states that all normed spaces are metric spaces if we define the metric $d(x,y) = \rho(x-y)$. I have proved the requirements to be a metric space except that  $d(x,y)= d(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in X$ only by definition of the normed space. How can I show this symmetry property?

Comment: Don't forget that you can write $x-y$ as $(-1)(y-x)$!

Comment: Oh my god @MikeF .Now,I got that thank you very much .